# Can't install Mediawiki Extension?

Tags: php, mediawiki

Trying to Install this [Mediawiki Extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Moderation#Installation) which helps in Moderation of any added content.

I have put all the files(step1 in above instructions) in the folder and also added the `require_once` line in `localsettings.php`(step2). Now next step(step3) is to update the database tables for this extension.

I am not able to figure out this step. I updated the database by going to `/mw-config/` but still whenever I am trying to edit any topic a Database error is coming.

Comment: You will need to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run the update script

```
php <wiki_directory>/maintenance/update.php
```